# How to make proxy configurations in a java program

Tags: java, networking

I have a PC which connects to internet through a proxy server. I'm able to browse google.com and all other sites. However i'm unable to ping google.com, smtp.gmail.com or any other websites . I'm trying send some automated mails through a java program, but every time it fails to connect to smtp.gmail.com. Is there any proxy configurations i need to make in my java program..??

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a proxy server for HTTP connections such as browsing google.com but are limited in you network connectivity. You would have to get a firewall opening made for you to connect to port 25 (465 if using SSL) to smtp.gmail.com to be able to send mail messages from that machine.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: set properties `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` either using `-D` when invoking Java, or using `Properties`.

For details, have a look at [Java Networking and Proxies](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.If you are behind a firewall, you need to configure proxy. To do so, use this code piece.

```
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "a.b.c.d");//replace a.b.c.d with your proxy IP
systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

Optionally,You might want to override DefaultAuthenticator. If your proxy requires authentication, you might have to do this as well.

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
   return new PasswordAuthentication("user","password".toCharArray());
   }
});
```